# Composer isn't getting vendor folder when I am trying to install yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, composer-php, yii2-advanced-app

Here is the scenario, I am following these instructions it is getting complete framework except vendor, folder.

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.0.3"
composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced yiiplus
```

I am getting below error, and **Vendor** folder isn't in directory.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Github access token here(in your cmd where this message is displaying Token:(hidden) )

Go to [Github](https://github.com/settings/tokens/new), (create account if you don't have)

Give token description and click on `Generate token` button.

Copy that token and paste into your cmd.

Hopefully if will work.